# I got problem because of android enviroment

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, environment

When I tried to

> react-native run-android

I get this error. I don't understand why?? Everything was working fine. I installed all android environment variables

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
(node:7516) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1367 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\furkan\FirstProject\FirstProject\node_modules\react-native-navigation\lib\android\app\build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-navigation'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-navigation'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Comment: I solved problem. in package.json and package-log.json I changed the part of "react-native-navigation"

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, you should post a proper answer below. It's encouraged to answer your own question. But please include more details in your answer about exactly what part you changed.